# Shell script Process PID logging and maintenance using exec

Tags: bash, shell, pid, exec

I am trying to launch a java process as a server and then might periodically need to restart/kill it at certain times. Since I use a shell script to launch java jvm(to build classpath), I thought of logging the shell script process id using  $$ and then run java as 
"exec java" so  that I can use the logged process id for killing the process and launching the new jvm. 
Is that the best way to do it? Any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion one of the best ways to launch, control and maintain java processes/daemons is by putting them under control of the tanuki service wrapper, see here for more information: http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com

Comment: service wrappers sound interesting. I will take a look at Tanuki and other options.